# Simple Blackjack/21 game in console

Tags: c++, c++11, game, playing-cards

I made a simple Blackjack/21 game in C++. It does not use any fancy graphics, just the console output. It is as simple as it can get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

void printData(int pTotal, int dCard) {

    std::cout << "\nYour total is " << pTotal;
    std::cout << "\nDealer has a " << dCard << " showing.\n";

}

int getCard() {

    return std::rand() % 11 + 2;

}

void turn(int& pTotal, char choice, bool& stay) {

    // If the user wants to hit
    if (choice == 'H' || choice == 'h') {

        // If the user hits 21 or above
        if ((pTotal += getCard()) >= 21) {

            std::cout << "Your total is " << pTotal;
            stay = true;

        }

        return;
    }

    // Since the only other option can be to stay, then stay
    stay = true;

}

int main() {

    bool stay;
    char choice = NULL;

    while (true) {

        std::cout << "================================";
        stay = false;

        // Initialize srand and get random card numbers
        std::srand(std::time(0));
        int dCard = getCard();
        int pTotal = getCard() + getCard();
        int dTotal = dCard + getCard();


        // Player's turn
        while (!stay) {

            printData(pTotal, dCard);
            std::cout << "[H]it or [S]tay?\n";
            std::cin >> choice;
            turn(pTotal, choice, stay);

        }

        stay = false;
        std::cout << "\n\nIt is now the dealer's turn!\n";

        // Dealer's turn
        while (dTotal <= 21 && !stay) {

            if (dTotal >= 17)
                stay = true;
            else
                dTotal += getCard();

        }

        // Display winner
        std::cout << "\n\nThe player has " << pTotal << ".\nThe dealer has " << dTotal << ".\n\n";
        if ((std::abs(21 - pTotal)) < (std::abs(21 - dTotal))) std::cout << "The player wins!\n";
        else std::cout << "The dealer wins!\n";

    }

}
```

1. Is this code efficient?
2. Is the code easy to read/understand and to follow?
3. Are variable names appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I want my money back!

```
Your total is 15
Dealer has a 4 showing.
[H]it or [S]tay?
s


It is now the dealer's turn!


The player has 15.
The dealer has 23.   <<=====

The dealer wins!     <<=====
```

Your casino is cheating! Also you're not handling aces, all face cards are supposed to have a value of 10, and there are 13 ranks in a suit but your `getCard` function can only return 11 different values (2 to 12).

This means that you can lose right off the bat:

```
$ ./a.out 
================================
Your total is 24       <<======     :-(
Dealer has a 9 showing.
[H]it or [S]tay?
```

---

In `turn`, if the player enters `h` and doesn't bust, you're not setting `stay` - this happens to work given the code flow, but it looks odd. Set it before returning.

If the user enters gibberish, you always interpret that as stay. That's not user-friendly.

In `main`:

```
bool stay;
char choice = NULL;
```

That's not a valid initializer for a `char` - chars are not pointers. And leaving a variable (`stay`) uninitialized is not a good idea. You should move `stay` inside the loop, only declare it when you give it its first value. (I'd also use two separate variables for the dealer and the player.)
Remove `choice` from main altogether. Only `turn` needs it, so handle the user input in there completely. (And have turn return hit/stay so you don't need that out parameter.)

This shouldn't be inside the loop:

```
std::srand(std::time(0));
```

You should initialize the RNG only once, do that at the very start of main. C++11 introduced new [random generation facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), you should look into them.

These lines are too long:

```
// Display winner
std::cout << "\n\nThe player has " << pTotal << ".\nThe dealer has " << dTotal << ".\n\n";
if ((std::abs(21 - pTotal)) < (std::abs(21 - dTotal))) std::cout << "The player wins!\n";
else std::cout << "The dealer wins!\n";
```

Try something like:

```
// Display winner
std::cout << "\n\nThe player has " << pTotal
          << ".\nThe dealer has " << dTotal << ".\n\n";

if ((std::abs(21 - pTotal)) < (std::abs(21 - dTotal))) {
  std::cout << "The player wins!\n";
} else {
  std::cout << "The dealer wins!\n";
}
```

And once you fix your logic so that a bust directly ends the players turn, and a dealer bust makes the player win, you can get rid of the `std::abs` since both scores will be at most 21.

Answer (score 2):

## Your deck isn't fair

This code will happily deal a card that's already been dealt:

> ```
> int getCard() {
>
>     return std::rand() % 11 + 2;
>
> }
> ```

Real Blackjack uses a *finite* set of cards, usually a fixed number of standard decks shuffled together.  The code here is equivalent to dealing from an *infinite* deck (or to replacing cards to be drawn again).

The difference may well be important to anyone using this program to practice their card-counting technique.

Answer (score -2):

Handle the Aces! (That's my only problem, I got a 22 at start)

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! The code's inability to handle aces properly has already been mentioned in the accepted answer, though. Can you provide any other advice?